# Should I exclude filtering for JSP files?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working with Spring-boot projects. I put jsp files under the location of 
`WEB-INF/views/`. I added spring security configurations and `apache-tiles` as my `ViewResolver`. Everytimes when I run the projects, I saw a lot of debug logs for Spring-Security's filters intercept for my jsp files as

```
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 Checking match of request : '/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp'; against '/css/**'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 Checking match of request : '/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp'; against '/js/**'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 Checking match of request : '/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp'; against '/images/**'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 Checking match of request : '/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp'; against '/webjars/**'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 Checking match of request : '/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: ''
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 8 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
```

I am not sure about the questions `Are those normal things ?`. I would like to know `should I ignore them` by adding below codes in my `SecurityConfig` class.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("**/*.jsp");
}
```

Comment: You should ignore them by disabling debug logging. It is DEBUG logging. You will see that for every request.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I can raise log-level to hide them but I would like to know these filters should be or not for jsp files and what would be the problem if I ignore them by spring-security configuration ?

Comment: Your security tags would stop working for one...

Comment: @M.Deinum *..Your security tags would stop working for one..* Hmm... this shouldn't be for my applications. Some of my jsp files contain `<sec:` tags from `spring-security-taglib`. If they don't work, I shouldn't ignore security filters for JSP files.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh I saw one .. `web.ignoring().antMatchers("**/*.jsp");` wont stop filtering the jsp files these contain `<sec:` tags but other jsp files did not intercept. Thank your for your guide sir.